# Which numbers in $(Z/NZ)^\times$ are of the form $a^2+11b^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $N\geq 1$ be an integer and we consider the $P(N)$ be the set of all the elements of $(Z/NZ)^\times$ of the form $a^2+11b^2$, with $a,b\in Z/NZ$.

I want to prove that $P(N)$ is equal to $(Z/NZ)^\times$ if $11|N$ and equal to the set of squares mod $11$ otherwise.

My attempt: since there are $p-(-11/p)$ pairs $(a,b)\in (Z/pZ)^2$ such that $a^2+11b^2=1$, maybe I could count the number of elements in $P(N)$ and show that it is equal to $\phi(N)$ if $11|N$. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If $11$ is not a square $\pmod N$, then we can get all the non-residues by letting $a=0$.  For example, with $N=13$ we can get represent the non-residues $(2,5,6,7,8,11)$ by taking $a=0$ and $b=(5,2,6,4,3,1)$.  And of course you can represent all the squares by taking $b=0$.

Comment: Even if $11$ is a square $\pmod N$...if you take $N=7$ we can represent $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ as $(a,b)=\{(1,0),(3,0),(1,2),(2,0),(1,1),(3,1)\}$

Comment: Should have said:  in my first comment I was assuming $N=p$, a prime.

Comment: @lulu Why does we represent all the non-residues if $11$ is a square? And what if $N$ is not a prime?

Comment: I don't know if we can always represent every class when $11$ is a square, I didn't think about it.  I gave you an example ($N=7$) in which we could, but I did not try to address the matter generally.  I suggest working more examples.

Comment: With a moment's thought, it is trivial:  we want to solve $a^2+b^2\equiv n\pmod p$, but there are $\frac {p+1}2$ expressions of the form $n-b^2$ and the same number of squares so there must be an overlap.  Hence it is always solvable.

Comment: @lulu very nice idea! And that works precisely when $p\neq 11$ (since after finding such a $b$ we also have to solve $11x\equiv b \pmod{p}$).

Comment: @lulu I think from now on its just a matter of using the Chinese Remainder theorem to go to the general case. If you want, you can write an answer and I'll accept. If not, I'll do it to help future readers.

Comment: Go ahead and write it up.  I'm not persuaded that the general case will be  straight forward, however.  At least, I'd want to study the case of $N=p^n$ first.